# react-stepzilla and React 16

Tags: reactjs, react-stepzilla

I am attempting to make use of react-stepzilla, but am getting an error when I install the package:

> react-stepzilla@4.7.2 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none is
>   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I am using `"react": "^16.5.2",`

Is the issue here that stepzilla doesn't support React 16.x? And is there a way around this?

At runtime, I get the error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/react-stepzilla/dist/main.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'promise' in 'D:\Software
>   Development\Repositories\GitHub\MyProj\node_modules\react-stepzilla\dist'
>   @ ./node_modules/react-stepzilla/dist/main.js 21:15-33

I also see this in the editor:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/newbreedofgeek/react-stepzilla/issues/105

Comment: Thanks for that. As that was a July comment, I'm guessing I should look for another options, as ... it seems stale. Damn. It looked good.

Comment: It could still work. The API mostly stayed the same between 15.x and 16.x

Comment: It would be nice, but the 'must install dependencies' error above is what is stumping me. (Added runtime error to post)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked a long time ago, it appears that react-stepzilla has been updated. It now requires a peer dependency of React 16.4.1. If you tried this again today it would probably not be an issue.

It was indeed the peer dependency that was causing the issue. There's no convenient way around that, though there are a few ways of dealing with it. This question has details on [how to handle peer dependency version conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288023/multiple-versions-of-same-peerdependency-required).